# need help on desired JSON output

Tags: c#, json.net

I have below class structures,

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int Size { get; set; } = 10;
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have list of messages like,

```
var messages = new List<Message>
            {
                new Message{ Size=10, Student=new Student{Id=1, Name="N1" } },
                new Message{ Size=20, Student=new Student{Id=2, Name="N2" } }
            };
```

which I want to write in `JSON` using `Newtonsoft.Json`,

```
using (var f = File.CreateText("C:\\Temp\\test.json"))
            {
                f.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages));
            }
```

This give below JSON output,

```
 [
  {
    "Size": 10,
    "Student": {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "N1"
    }
  },
  {
    "Size": 20,
    "Student": {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "N2"
    }
  }
]
```

But I would like below output (**without size and only one time root element student**),

```
{
  "Student": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "N1"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "N2"
    }
  ]
}
```

whats need to be done here? Thanks!

Comment: You can put all messages' students in a collection class and serialize it.

Comment: This might help `var myObj = new KeyValuePair<string,Student[]>("Student",messages.Select(s=>s.Student).ToArray())` and then just serialize it push to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refine your data to get desired result

first

```
var refindedResult = new { Students = messages.Select(m => m.Student) };
```

second pass it to json convertor

```
using (var f = File.CreateText("C:\\Temp\\test.json"))
{
    f.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(refindedResult ));
}
```

Comment: Please make it Students

Comment: is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

```
//f.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages));
  f.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages.Select(m => m.Student)));
```

or, when you want a root object (Student**s**, not Student)

```
  f.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
       new { Students = messages.Select(m => m.Student) } ));
```

Comment: root element is not added by this

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write a `StudentModel` class.

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

use linq get student collection from `messages`, then `SerializeObject` on it.

```
var res = new StudentModel()
{
    Student = messages.Select(x => x.Student)
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```